# Split array(bigint) to multiple rows of bigint

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I'm querying some **`data (SQL, presto)`**, each item can be the parent or child of another. The `parent IDs` and the `child IDs` are stored in the row for that primary ID as an array(bigint). Each task could be the child of multiple parents.

It looks something like:

```
id | parent_ids | child_ids
1 | [3] | []
2 | [3] | []
3 | [] | [2,1]
4 | [] | [5]
5 | [4, 6] | []
6 | [] | [5]
```

I want a list of all of the `parent Ids` and each of the `children` as additional rows for that parent:

```
id | child
3 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 5
6 | 5
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select p.parent_id as id, t.id as child_id
from t cross join 
     unnest(t.parent_ids) p(parent_id)
```

Comment: I think that's done it! thank you! I think I understand how this works : unnest parent_ids will pull out each parent id in the list for each id and create a new row, the original row id becomes the child id and the unnested parent id for that row becomes the id. I can see that the purpose of p(parent_id) is (probably) to name the unnested parent_ids column parent_id, but I don't understand why p()? are you please able to explain?

Comment: `p(parent_id)` is just the name given to the unnested column.

Comment: Note that if the `parent_ids` may be `NULL` or empty, and you still want to retain such rows in the output, you may want to use `LEFT JOIN UNNEST(t.parent_ids) p(parent_id) ON true` instead of `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.parent_ids) p(parent_id)`.

Comment: thanks - that edit helped me to understand. in this case, p is the name of the table so could read it 'unnest(t.parent_ids) as p(parent)id'? appreciate the help!